# Alternative word for "statistics"?

Tags: single-word-requests, technical, synonyms

Statistics seems to mean both numerical records (e.g. "baseball statistics"), and also the *analysis* of that data (e.g. average, ANOVA, confidence intervals, etc.)

In my work at the moment, I need to deal with statistics in both senses, and it's getting confusing - when someone says "I was working on the stats", I don't know whether they mean they were gathering data, or analysing it!

What is another word for statistics, that differentiates these meanings? I prefer to use statistics to refer the methods of statistical analysis, so is there another way to refer to numerical data? I feel that just using "numerical data" is both cumbersome, and a little too broad.

Comment: By   *'another way to refer to numerical data'* you mean *collection of data*?

Comment: @Josh61 I mean the data itself: "What are his statistics?" "Well, he's 5'9, 163lb, brown hair..."

Comment: Mark Twain had this to say: "There are three kinds of lies: *lies*, *damned lies* and *statistics*."
- [Mark Twain's Own Autobiography: The Chapters from the North American Review](http://www.twainquotes.com/Statistics.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the term you need is just ***[data](http://subjectguides.uwaterloo.ca/stats_data)***:

***Data vs Statistics vs Information***

> - These terms are often used interchangeably, but they are actually very different, as shown in the following table.

- Table: Movie Rentals per Month by University Students

***Data:***

> - 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, etc.
> - 10, 15, 12,  14, 18 etc.

***Statistics:***

> - average number of rentals: 2.5
> - average number of rentals: 14

***Information:***

> - 20 university students rent fewer than 5 movies per month
> - 20 university students rent more than 10 movies per month

*Statistics are generally presentation-ready; Data will need to be manipulated in order for it to be meaningful.*